# KnockoutJs, cannot get the correct value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I upload my code to jsFiddle, you can test it there.

http://jsfiddle.net/2RPsw/1/

here's the problem, instead getting a fulln name, it shows the source code of the function.  If I use ko.computed, it will work.  what I did below should also be fine.  Can someone please explain to me why its showing the source code, not the value.

```
            <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
            <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
            <p>Full name: <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></p>?
```

KO code:

```
function AppViewModel() {

    self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    self.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
    self.fullName = function(){
        return  self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();

    };
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());?
```

**UPDATE:**

To answer TCM's question.  why I dont want to use ko.computed.  not that I dont want to use it, simply because I am confused and not sure when to use it. for example

following code is from knockout first tutorial. its not using ko.computegd, but it works.

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro

```
self.capName = function(){
    var curVal = self.lastName();
    self.lastName(curVal.toUpperCase());
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using ko.computed:

```
 self.fullName = ko.computed(function(){
        return  self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();

 },this);
```

and that will make sure whenever your value of `firstName` or `lastName` changed the changes will be reflected in your ko.computed function and you don't have to manually update the span's value.

For further explanation, you can read this:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

More or less the same example is given on this link.

If you don't want to use ko.computed, see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/2RPsw/10/

Comment: i know ko.computed will get it work, but I dont understand why not using it will cause problem.

Comment: @feelexit: Did you see my jsfiddle link? You are missing round brackets in your span binding of full name.

Comment: ye, i figure it out why my code is not working,  I should use fullName() in my view.